# MySQL OHLC from Tic query

Tags: mysql

I have a table containing a list of individual prices for a variety of companies eg.

+-------+---------+---------+------+

| Symbol| TTime   | TPrice  |Volume|

+-------+---------+---------+------+

|  AAM  |  101549 | 1303.15 |  100 |

|  AAM  |  120405 | 1308.23 |    2 |

|  AAM  |  132142 | 1302.16 |   11 |

|  AAM  |  145120 | 1307.75 |    1 |

+-------+---------+---------+------+

(There are multiple symbols but I can get those no problems)

I'm using the following

```
SELECT tic.Symbol, 
       tic.TDate,
      (Case when 
            tic.TTime = Min(tic.TTime) 
      then tic.TPrice  end) as `Open`,
      Max(tic.TPrice) AS High,
      Min(tic.TPrice) AS Low,
      (Case when 
            tic.TTime = Max(tic.TTime)
      then tic.TPrice end ) as `Close`,
      Sum(Volume) AS Volume,
      Max(tic.TTime) 
      FROM  tblfinalasxtic AS tic GROUP BY Symbol LIMIT 10;
```

I'm getting one major issues

A Close price is only generated when there is one time for the whole day or if there is only multiple entries at the same time a close will generate. If the time frame is as the example no close price..

The open works fine my assumption would be that the max would work but no go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Essentially I came to a resolution that works like this

1:/ Create a table for tic values ** Make sure you create the ID column **

```
CREATE TABLE price_tic (
            `id` INT(10) NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
            `T` VARCHAR(3) NULL,
            `SysDateTime` DATETIME NULL,
            `TIC` FLOAT NULL,
            `Volume` FLOAT NULL,
            PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
            )
            COLLATE='latin1_bin'
            ENGINE=MEMORY
            ROW_FORMAT=DEFAULT
```

2:/ Next create a temporary table for Open High Low, Volume, OI etc

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE symbol_ohl
            (ExchDate DATE,
            ExchTime TIME )
            ENGINE = MEMORY
            AS(SELECT 
                   DATE_FORMAT(`SysDateTime`,'%Y-%m-%d') AS ExchDate,
                   DATE_FORMAT(`SysDateTime`,'%H:%i:00') AS ExchTime,
                   DATE_FORMAT(`SysDateTime`,'%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:00') AS ExchDateTime,
                   `TIC` AS `OPEN`,
                   MAX(`TIC`) AS `HIGH`,
                   MIN(`TIC`) AS `LOW`,
                   SUM(Volume) AS `Volume`,
                   COUNT(`TIC`) AS `OpnInt`
                   FROM symbol_tic
                   GROUP BY ExchDateTime
                   ORDER BY ExchDateTime)
```

3:/ Next create a temporary table for the close prices that uses the id number to join to itself so that you can order it correctly.

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE symbol_cls
             (SysDate DATE,
             SysTime TIME, 
             ExchTime TIME )
             ENGINE = MEMORY
             AS(SELECT
                    `TIC` AS `CLOSE`,
                    DATE_FORMAT(`SysDateTime`,'%Y-%m-%d') AS `SysDate`,
                    DATE_FORMAT(`SysDateTime`,'%H:%i:00') AS SysTime,
                    DATE_FORMAT(`SysDateTime`,'%H:%i:00') AS ExchTime,
                    DATE_FORMAT(`SysDateTime`,'%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:00') AS ExchDateTime
                    FROM symbol_tic
                    INNER JOIN
                    (SELECT MAX(id) AS id
                    FROM symbol_tic 
                    GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(`SysDateTime`,'%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:00')) 
                    ids ON symbol_tic.id = ids.id)
```

4:/ Finally merge the resulting temporary tables, I'm using Replace INTO for various reasons but you get the idea

```
REPLACE INTO symbol_working
        (`ExchDate`, `ExchTime`, `SysDate`, `SysTime`, `ExchDateTime`,
        `SysDateTime`, `OPEN`, `HIGH`, `LOW`, `CLOSE`, `Volume`, `OpnInt`)
        SELECT
                symbol_ohl.`ExchDate` AS ExchDate,
                symbol_ohl.`ExchTime` AS ExchTime,
                symbol_cls.`SysDate` AS 'SysDate',
                symbol_cls.`SysTime` AS 'SysTime',
                symbol_ohl.`ExchDateTime` As ExchDateTime,
                CONCAT(symbol_cls.`SysDate`, ' ',symbol_cls.`SysTime`) As SysDateTime,
                symbol_ohl.`OPEN`,
                symbol_ohl.`HIGH`,
                symbol_ohl.`LOW`,
                symbol_cls.`CLOSE`,
                symbol_ohl.Volume AS `Volume`,
                symbol_ohl.OpnInt AS `OpnInt`
                FROM 
                (symbol_ohl JOIN symbol_cls 
                ON (symbol_ohl.ExchDateTime = symbol_cls.ExchDateTime))
```

Hope this helps someone.

This works quite quickly I'm running it on a daily output of the S&P emini and it takes a couple of seconds to run.